# Converting input object type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I need to alternate the type of an object passed to a function, so every method inside the object receive a modified `this`:

```js
create({
  /*
   * Hello
   */
  foo(): string {
    console.log(this); // should be { foo: string, bar: number, baz: Record<string, number> }
    console.log(this.bar); // should be number
    console.log(this.baz); // should be Record<string, number>
    return "Hello";
  },


  /*
   * World
   */
  bar(): number {
    console.log(this.foo); // should be string
    console.log(this.baz); // should be Record<string, number>
    return 123;
  },

  /*
   * World
   */
  baz(): Record<string, number> {
    console.log(this.foo); // should be string
    console.log(this.bar); // should be number
    return {
      foo: 123,
      bar: 456,
    };
  },
});
```

For the create function I tried the following approach without much of a success:

```js
type PropMethod = () => any;

type Property<P extends PropMethod = any> = P extends PropMethod ? P : never;

type Context<T extends Record<string, Property>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Property ? ReturnType<T[K]> : never;
};

type Properties<P extends Record<string, Property>> = {
  [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends (...args: infer Args) => infer R
    ? (this: Context<P>, ...args: Args) => R
    : never;
};

function create<
  C extends Record<string, Property>,
>(input: Properties<C>) {
  /**
   * Body implementation
   */
}
```

Obviously, I'm getting `this: Context<Record<string, any>>` and every property inside the functions is `any` too.

Is it even possible to achieve such typing with TS? One of the requirements is that there should be no hardcoded types and as the whole thing is an abstraction.

Also, it'd be awesome if someone could suggest a better title for the question.

Comment: Please include `Args`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w86Q4m) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: done. but it doesn't make any difference, tbh. internally those methods are converted to somewhat looking like regular getters. the only reason why i need them not to be getters is so that I can assemble multiple objects like that into one

Comment: Okay I'll write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to get the kind of behavior you're looking for is to use the "magic" [`ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype).  It's "magic" because even though the [definition of `ThisType<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/546440384816e10e1c9c495fbedc4728ec576914/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1645-L1648) it is just an empty interface, it is special-cased by the compiler to indicate the type you want the `this` context of methods to be treated as.

Here's how I'd use it for your code:

```
function create<M extends object>(input:
  M & ThisType<{ [K in keyof M]:
    M[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : M[K]
  }>) { }
```

So I'm saying that the type of `input` is the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `M`, but that the `this` context of its properties should be inferred as

```
{ [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : M[K] }
```

where we're [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the methods of `M` to just their return types via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)

---

Let's test it out:

```
create({
  foo(): string {
    this.bar.toFixed(); // okay
    Object.values(this.baz).map(x => x.toFixed()); // okay
    return "Hello";
  },
  bar(): number {
    this.foo.toUpperCase(); // okay
    Object.values(this.baz).map(x => x.toFixed()); // okay
    return 123;
  },
  baz(): Record<string, number> {
    this.foo.toUpperCase(); // okay
    this.bar.toFixed(); // okay
    return {
      foo: 123,
      bar: 456,
    };
  },
});
```

Looks good!  The types of `this.foo`, `this.bar`, and `this.baz` are exactly what you wanted them to be.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgLKJoAe2YAJgM6JwBGAVmtAHwAUMYADiFAFwBQiRAQBkiACoALGBTEBPDrgDeiANoBpRO0QBrNLLjAhAXX6DBedUcIk05KiwB0TjCgDmFHogxhZASkQAvEyaYMBoKIgASogA-FGInhZqRgKIAL5M-sppfLmomNgsiqnAcHAsvp4UUCjsrojFZohQUhQONC4OUHAAYjBEaGQVANyIAPRj1NoYsqmCAPL0jFAOAG4YADYgaBQsLdLtGABevg4AthgcLESBwURdvf2DFb6jE1Mzc4joUCAoSAAiAASaA2GzgAOGqTSABpUh0UBVPGAQGcaOEGl99m1SnAHgBVDgKFAAYQwFDQI3Gkzg01mTUWDGga022122MOJ3Ol2ut0Q926fQGQ18r2pH3pZh+fyQAEYAEwAZihglh8OOSKijDgKDIOGqtTArhhiBRaPCwUaZg5uIJRPCZIpVPetM+TQ5CIeQueYpddK+0v+mKaglxngVirhIcQCM8ABYAKwANijZjSKvScLSr1yQA)

Comment: oh, didn't know about the compiler stuff. `ThisType` confused me at the beginning by being an empty object. that explains a lot. thank you! totally solved my task with this thing. awesome